# Folder where bash script resides when running via ln -s

Tags: bash, posix

In */usr/local/bin* I have a 'ln -s' to */usr/local/foo/bash.script*, and in this latter script I want to know the current */usr/local/foo* directory, so that I can run a secondary script from that folder.

Now, I tried *dirname $0*, but that gives me the */usr/local/bin* folder instead. What should I be using in the *bash.script* to get the */usr/local/foo* folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `readlink`, e.g.

```
d=$0

while readlink $d >/dev/null; do
  d=`readlink $d`
done
echo $d
```

*EDIT*:

I am not sure if that works on other Unix OS, but if you are on linux the above can be simplified by using

```
d=`readlink -f $0`

echo $d
```

see

```
readlink --help
```

Comment: Thanx for the pointers! I still need to combine with dirname, and I saw the readlink -f, doing the above in one command ... any idea on how portable that is?

Comment: @Egon: `-f` worked for on cygwin (on Win-7-64bit) too. But it doesn't work on MacOS.

Comment: Ah, well, that's good enough for my needs, because it is part of a script only for Linux :) thanx!